# How to train a network with multiple inputs and multiple outputs

Tags: machine-learning, function

How to train a network with multiple inputs and multiple outputs
I have a dataset of (400,256) 400 examples with 256 features.
and each example has its corresponding output array
(400,256) 400 examples with their 256 outputs.

Once you have trained the network that takes an array of 256 inputs and predicts the corresponding array of 256 outputs.

try classifier but all the examples i found are for multiple input with only one output.

Comment: What’s the problem with making a network that has 256 outputs?

Comment: Is this a matter of the software implementation of such a network, such as in TensorFlow, Keras, or Torch?